# What controls the paths in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter

I have tried repeatedly to delete everything Jupyter related across my system. Nevertheless, even when freshly installing Jupyter in a virtualenv when I type `jupyter --paths` I get

```
config:
    /Users/$user/.jupyter
    /Users/$user/env/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /Users/$user/Library/Jupyter
    /Users/$user/env/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /Users/$user/Library/Jupyter/runtime
```

Where is this and how do I reset or remove these paths? Where would this hidden config file be?